# Lambda ephemeral size error: no space left on device

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I created an AWS Lambda function in us-east-1 with ephemeral size of 512MB it was running fine. However, when running this same Lambda function in eu-west-1 I got an error in the Lambda function logs:

> no space left on device

I have the exact same setup in both regions, however they are in different accounts. Not sure why it's asking for more space in eu-west-1.

Comment: There is not nearly enough information in your question for anyone to help you. Is your Lambda function downloading something to /tmp, or otherwise generating files that are stored on the ephemeral storage? Is this error happening during deployment, during the first invocation, or only after the function has been invoked many times?

Comment: Sorry for not being descriptive here.
is your lambda function downloading something to /tmp? yes i'm downloading a yaml file.
The error is happening during the first invocation.

Comment: Is the yaml file huge? That doesn't sound like the type of thing that would typically cause an error like this. Is your Lambda function huge? Or does it include a lot of Lambda layers or something? It sounds like it may be just on the verge of being too big, and something slightly different in that other region just happens to push it over the limit.

Comment: yes my lambda function is huge - Is there's a way to view the usage of ephemeral storage during or after invocation?

Comment: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/using-larger-ephemeral-storage-for-aws-lambda/

Comment: Also, please note that the Lambda function should delete any files in `/tmp/` before exiting because the environment can be reused for future executions. This could cause the disk space to be totally consumed if files from previous executions are not deleted.